# Polygon contains circle has longer perimeter

Tags: geometry, logic

I need a proof that a polygon circumscribing a circle has a longer perimeter.
I use the following axioms that will be agreed by everyone.

1. Line is the shortest path between $2$ points. (With that I can prove a polygon that is inside a circle and each of its vertices touches the circle is smaller :) )
2. If we have 2 circles with different radii. than the perimeter of the circle with the longer radius will be longer than the other's.

I tried and I could not solve it.

Maybe they are not enough.

And the definition of a circle is all the points that has the same distance from a singular point. Not the limit of polygons or something so please don't use it.

Thanks in advance for any helpers.

Comment: It's confusing. "Has longer perimeter" than what? The circle that it contains?

Comment: whats confusing??? 2 circles with radius r1 and r2. lets say r2>r1 than the perimeter of the circle with radius r2 is longer than the perimeter of the circle with the radius r1. hope its clearer for you now

Comment: It is a futile attempt to try to axiomatize geometry from scratch. It took the humankind thousands of years. In addition, after Descartes, we often look at geometry not as a study of an axiomatic theory but of the affine space $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Having said that, at least for a polygon with inscribed circle, you can reason as follows: let $O$ be the centre of the circle, $A$ be a point where the polygon touches the circle, $B$ the neighbouring vertex of the polygon and $B'$ the point where segment $OB$ intersects the circle. Then the area of the circle sector $OAB'$ is $\frac{1}{2}OA\cdot\overset{\frown}{AB'}$ whereas the area of the triangle $OAB$ is $\frac{1}{2}OA\cdot AB$. As the former is smaller than the latter, you have $\overset{\frown}{AB'}<AB$. You can extend this proof to the case where the circle does not touch the polygon.

Comment: i dont agree/ understnad. i agree to the point of the area of OAB > OA"AB'". "AB'" is the curve on the circle. how you computed their area is not well understood. and i might just mention... when i drew the picture it looks that "AB'" is longer than AB!!!!

Comment: @Okosh: Bishop has a good idea, express area of circular sector in terms of arc length and radius.

Answer (score 0):

The *isoperimetric inequality* says that among all shapes with a fixed area the circle has the smallest possible perimeter.

The fact that you want follows from this: The perimeter of a polygon is greater than the corresponding circle with the same area, which in turn is bigger than the perimeter of any smaller circle.

I recognize this isn't as elementary as you were hoping for. There are some nice fairly elementary proofs of this though, using what's called Steiner or Schwarz symmetrization (in case people feel like googling). They do use some sort of limiting argument though, but to be honest I think that may be unavoidable: How are you even defining the length of a circular arc without some sort of limit?

Comment: its makes a cyclic proof. i ned the proof i asked for to prove pie exist or the ratio beetween the circle to the radius is constant. the isoperimetric inequality uses the knowlegde of pie and trigonometry. like they use the fact the the lengh of the arc is the radius times the angle. so a proof from that direction wont work for me.

Comment: i try solve it with limits but i cant show that the lower bound of the permiter of the upper polygon is the lengh of the perimeter of the circle. maybe its equal or smaller. im trying really hard. but cant continue.